# Creating missing values over a timespan for 'current balance' in a financial database

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I have a set of Accounts, and over time journal entries are entered against those accounts:

| Account |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

Journal Entries:

| Date | Account | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 20 |
| 2022-01-01 | C | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | D | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 70 |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 40 |
| 2022-01-03 | D | 100 |
| 2022-01-04 | C | 25 |

I now want to generate a row for each date + account, showing the balance as-of that date, effectively doing missing sequence and 'pulling forwards' values for the interim values:

| Date | Account | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 20 |
| 2022-01-01 | C | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | D | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 80 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | *20* |
| 2022-01-02 | C | *0* |
| 2022-01-02 | D | *0* |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 120 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | *20* |
| 2022-01-03 | C | *0* |
| 2022-01-03 | D | 100 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | *120* |
| 2022-01-04 | B | *20* |
| 2022-01-04 | C | 25 |
| 2022-01-04 | D | *100* |

It's essentially like a sparsely populated matrix:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 80 | : | : | : |
| 2022-01-03 | 120 | : | : | 100 |
| 2022-01-04 | : | : | 25 | : |

where all of the colons represent a number pulled from the most recent value above, as I need to show a value for every date, regardless of whether there was a journal entry or not.

I guess if I omit the window function and find a way of injecting zeros as the change for all the missing values, I could then perform the window function against the resulting dataset as the zeros would not affect the running totals, but is there any way to do this efficiently?

This is all straightforward in something like Analysis Services, but is there a relatively efficient way of doing the same thing in SQL?

Comment: Create a calendar table (or use a CTE) with all dates in the desired range and then left join from the calendar to your journal entries on date.

Comment: if there are no Journal entries for a date, do you need the date as well? with 0 across all accounts?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a cross join to get the missing rows. (DBFiddle at the bottom)

The cross join will produce a set where each Account has each date from Journal
Then we can join again on Journal to retrieve the other columns

```
declare @Account table (Account varchar(10))
declare @Journal table (JournalDate date, Account varchar(10), Change int)

insert into @Account values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')
insert into @Journal values ('20220101', 'A', 10), ('20220101', 'B', 20), ('20220101', 'C', 0), ('20220101', 'D', 0), 
('20220102', 'A', 70), ('20220103', 'A', 40), ('20220103', 'D', 100), ('20220104', 'C', 25)


select jc.JournalDate,
       a.Account,
       j.Change
from   @Account a
  cross join (select distinct j.JournalDate from @Journal j) jc
  left join @Journal j on jc.JournalDate = j.JournalDate and a.Account = j.Account
```

the result  is

| JournalDate | Account | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 20 |
| 2022-01-01 | C | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | D | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 70 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | NULL |
| 2022-01-02 | C | NULL |
| 2022-01-02 | D | NULL |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 40 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | NULL |
| 2022-01-03 | C | NULL |
| 2022-01-03 | D | 100 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | NULL |
| 2022-01-04 | B | NULL |
| 2022-01-04 | C | 25 |
| 2022-01-04 | D | NULL |

Here is a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d13e401148f43fe3c7788727f33f09) to try it yourself

**EDIT**

If you have gaps in the dates in journal, and also want to close these gaps, then cross join on a tally table.

In this example there will also be rows for date 2022-01-05 while this date is not in table Journal

```
;with calendar as
( select cast('20220101' as datetime) as cDate
  union all 
  select dateadd(day, 1, cDate)
  from   calendar
  where  cDate < dateadd(day, -1, '20220106')
)
select cDate,
       a.Account,
       j.Change 
from   @Account a
  cross join Calendar c
  left join @Journal j on c.cDate = j.JournalDate and a.Account = j.Account
order by 1, 2
```

Here is the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9de5eea7e21492e615a4c48cd878ca22)